# Why is camel case used in 'getElementById' but not in 'onclick'?

Tags: javascript

While learning JavaScript, I noticed that some of the functions, for instance `getElementById()`, are in camel case while the `onclick` is not.

I would like to know why there is a difference in the function naming in JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
```

Comment: because it is too late to change those properties to follow the convention they later established ?

Comment: for this specific example, I think it is because "click" (lower case) is the event type (e.g. addEventListener("click",...), and camel casing it is as onClick might have been considered misleading.

Comment: Worth noting that the things mentioned (`getElementById`, `onclick`, `innerHTML`) are all properties/methods on HTML entities that are exposed to JavaScript by the user agent, rather than parts of the JavaScript spec itself.

Comment: Not sure. Why do you not capitalize the word `I`?

Comment: @CrazyTrain, Do you mean capitalize single letters?

Comment: @Ivan: No, I mean the first person singular pronoun.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Could be a holdover from their native language, which does not always capitalize the FPSP, e.g., German "ich". Or they're just not aware of the convention. Not really relevant.

Comment: @DaveNewton: "Not really relevant" It's as relevant as the question.

Comment: @CrazyTrain ¯\(°_o)/¯ I think it's a reasonable question, but don't believe SO is the place to ask it.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Certainly reasonable that a person might be curious, though it's a trivial matter of little relevance if any. I agree that it's not within the parameters of a suitable SO question. A programmer's curiosity doesn't necessarily translate to a programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick` is a property that has its roots as an HTML attribute, first established in the very early days of the Web - - back before we had standards. As JavaScript (and ECMAScript) evolved, standards emerged.

This is why the web of today has many "exceptions" to what we now consider to be standards. We just can't go back and change what has become "de facto" standards.